# How do you properly configure a contrib logger?

Tags: c#, akka.net

The Wiki is vague in describing how to configure a logger.  I'm using

```cs
var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(@"
    akka {
        loggers = [""Akka.NLog.Event.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.NLog""]
        stdout-loglevel = INFO
        loglevel = INFO
        log-config-on-start = on
    }"
);
```

and have installed Akka.NLog from Nuget but get an exception when I create the actor system stating 'Logger specified in config cannot be found: "Akka.NLog.Event.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.NLog"'.

What is the correct configuration string for a contrib logger?

Comment: I agree, the wiki page is too vague.  Wish it had a concrete example for each logger.  Its not so obvious what the class/assembly it should be.

Comment: @irperez me too! I'll make sure we add that.

Comment: @Aaronontheweb I added the NLog config settings to the documentation in GitHub the other day.  We just need it for the other loggers.

Answer (score 5):

The correct HOCON configuration should look like this:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.Logger.NLog"]
}
```

To configure a custom logger, you just need to pass in a [FQN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx) into the `akka.loggers` HOCON field.

So if you want to use a user-defined logger `Foo.Loggers.MyCustomLogger` in assembly `Foo.Loggers` AND your original NLog logger, your HOCON will look like this:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["Foo.Loggers.MyCustomLogger,Foo.Loggers","Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger,Akka.Logger.NLog"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your exception points out, that fully qualified type name for logger you've used is not correct. Either you haven't provided correct assembly in your project, or type name is invalid.

At the present moment Akka logger with NLog support is now accessible with:

```
install-package Akka.Logger.NLog
```

NLog logger itself is accessible with `Akka.Logger.NLog.NLogLogger, Akka.Logger.NLog` fully qualified name.